# How can I use tf.identity to make a copy of a list of tesnors (not just a single tensor)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried this

```
weights = {
'wc1': tf.get_variable('wc1', shape=(8,8,4,32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'wc2': tf.get_variable('wc2', shape=(4,4,32,64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'wc3': tf.get_variable('wc3', shape=(3,3,64,64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'wd1': tf.get_variable('wd1', shape=(7744,512), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'wd2': tf.get_variable('wd2', shape=(512,action_size), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'bc1': tf.get_variable('bc1', shape=(32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bc2': tf.get_variable('bc2', shape=(64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bc3': tf.get_variable('bc3', shape=(64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bd1': tf.get_variable('bd1', shape=(512), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bd2': tf.get_variable('bd2', shape=(action_size), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
```

}

and then

```
weight_copies = [tf.identity(weights) for x in range(10)]
```

but I get following error

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got {'wc1': , 'wc2': , 'wc3': , 'wd1': , 'wd2': , 'bc1': , 'bc2': , 'bc3': , 'bd1': , 'bd2': }

Now my question is how I can do this without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weights` is a dictionary, so you need to iterate over the values.

```
weight_copies = [tf.identity(v) for v in weights.values()]
```

If you want your output to be a dictionary as well, iterate of the `item`s.

```
weight_copies = {k: tf.identity(v) for k, v in weights.items()}
```